# Angular 8 Ng2PageScrollModule not scroll well

Tags: html, angular

When I click on any option of the options in the menu it always scroll down to the same place

It always stop at

```
<app-education ></app-education>
```

How can I fix this ??

This is My code

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a pageScroll href="#header">Home</a></li>
            <li><a pageScroll href="#education">Education</a></li>
            <li><a pageScroll href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a pageScroll href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a pageScroll href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>
        <a id="header"></a>
        <app-header ></app-header>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a id="education"></a>
        <app-education ></app-education>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a id="skills"></a>
        <app-skills></app-skills>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a id="projects" name="projects"></a>
        <app-main-projects></app-main-projects>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a id="contact" name="contact"></a>
        <app-contact></app-contact>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: someone know  ?
need some help